# Changing display of content

Tags: 7, theming

I've got custom content-type with several groups and fields. I wanted to change default display of that content-type. I created the node--my_content_type.tpl.php file, and copied the node.tpl.php file into it. Mostly, I want to change display of fields of that content-type, but in that file I've got only a line.

```
print render($content);
```

So, I don't have the opportunity to chance display of fields. I want to have field1 on the left and field2 on the right, not one after another as its default.

Could someone help me, please?